# How copy files from file-name list and unconditional keep existing file in destination?

Tags: debian, files, file-copy, cpio

How copy files from file-name list and unconditional keep existing file in destination?

Note cpio is overwrite older existing files by default:

```
$ dpkg -L libgcc1 libstdc++6 |grep -e '^/lib/' -e '^/usr/lib/' |  cpio -pdv ./test
./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu
cpio: ./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 not created: newer or same age version exists
./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
cpio: ./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 not created: newer or same age version exists
cpio: ./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 not created: newer or same age version exists
0 blocks
$ touch -ht 200102030405 $(find  . )
$ dpkg -L libgcc1 libstdc++6 |grep -e '^/lib/' -e '^/usr/lib/' |  cpio -pdv ./test
./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu
./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
3222 blocks
$ #same version
$ dpkg -L libgcc1 libstdc++6 |grep -e '^/lib/' -e '^/usr/lib/' |  cpio -pdv ./test
./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu
cpio: ./test/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 not created: newer or same age version exists
./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
cpio: ./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 not created: newer or same age version exists
cpio: ./test/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 not created: newer or same age version exists
0 blocks
$ cp --version
cp (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjorn Granlund, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.
$
```

Comment: cpio shouldn't overwrite files unless instructed to.

Comment: I'm tested for this ,see my update .@RamanSailopal

Comment: There is no way to do this with cpio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with `cpio`.

You however may use `star` to do the job. Just call:

```
star -xpk < archive-name
```

BTW: I am not sure whether GNU cpio behaves correectly but cpio is often used in system management because it has an undocumented feature to extract files first into a temporary name and if this succeeded, to call `rename(2)` to replace the old file in a non-destuctive way. So the official `cpio` (not necessarily GNU cpio) behaves like the `install` program.

If you like to get this behavior with star, add the `-install` option.